# Max Heart Rate during Workout Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, ios, health.app

I am wondering if it's possible to set a max heart rate during a workout in the new Apple Watch 6. It's the only feature that I need in a new watch. If it doesn't have it I'm buying a garmin watch.

Kr,
V.

Comment: What happens when you set a Mac heart rate in your ideal / requirements? I record workouts using the Apple Watch and have several apps that read the workout data and show me heart rate zones, times, and much more. I’m not sure how to answer what “have it” means.

Comment: @bmike I want to lower my heart rate which means I have to run at a max heart rate for training.

Comment: Aah - so you just look at the watch periodically and slow down or speed up? The display is highly configurable so that would work well IMO.

Comment: @bmike not really that I want to look periodically, I want the watch to notify me.

Comment: What I found very strange is that nobody asked this question before, this is a basic runners question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any third party apps to have your heart rate sampled all the time and displayed on the watch. You can customize each workout type to include or exclude a dozen metrics for the Outdoor Run type. Indoor run is the same and I don't use it, but the treadmill integration is amazing from what I hear when you sync your watch to equipment that will visually show you what telemetry the watch is broadcasting (with your opt in permission, of course).

[image]

Here is what the phone interface looks like for you to alter what is shown during the workout image above.

[image]

So if you didn’t care so much about pace, you could edit out both pace items and see this instead during your run:

[image]

Garmin makes some great product, so I would choose based on where you want your data in the end - which app ecosystem is better for you. Heart Rate zones are going to be easy to set / manage / report on both platforms as it's so obvious and easy to measure.

Comment: Hi Mike! is it possible to show a screenshot what you see after you click on heart rate?

Comment: Nothing happens on the phone, this is where you customize the workout screen on the watch. https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/adjust-your-workout-settings-apde0be691be/watchos  Are you asking what the watch looks like in a run?

Comment: Hey Mike, I’m looking for a screenshot of where you set that heart rate effective.